# Как правильно настроить slick слайдер?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, slider, slick.js

Всем привет!
Что-то разобраться не могу как сделать, чтобы 3 слайда сразу показывало, а то у меня по одному лишь. Но и чтобы были стрелочки, чтобы можно было их прокручивать бесконечно.

Вот результат залитый на хостинг(блок **МДИС - ЭТО**) - http://silencer.website/mdis/index.html, 
а вот codepen - http://codepen.io/SilencerWeb/pen/BWxjBz?editors=1010

Настройки слайдера:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.about__content').slick({
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      initialSlide: 1,
      centerMode: true,
      variableWidth: true,
      focusOnSelect: true,
      infinite: true,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 6000,
      arrows: true,
      appendArrows: ".about__controllers",
      prevArrow: ".about__prev",
      nextArrow: ".about__next"
    });
  });
```

Но вот в чем подвох, результаты различаются. В кодпене показывает сразу 3 слайда, а на хостинге лишь один, что делать не знаю, идей нет. Может это потому-что я у себя в продакшне чуток поправил стили slick слайдера(файл slick.scss)? Но я там лишь убрал флоаты у элементов, т.к. они мешали, потому-что я использую флексы. Бьюсь с этой задачей уже несколько дней, надеюсь кто-нибудь из вас мне поможет =) 
Заранее благодарю!)

**P.S:** Вот такой слайдер примерно должен получиться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вроде все идентично...

Comment: из-за autoplay невозможно посмотреть ничего

Comment: и да это из-за флекса `space-between` стоит заменить на `center` и задать отступы

Comment: @SilencerWeb напишите, в таком случае, ответ со своим результатом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все-таки да, проблема была в том, что я изменил дефолтные стили в файле slick.scss. Вставил нетронутый файл, убрал флексы у слайдера, все заработало более-менее, потом пришлось каждому слайду создать обертку, чтобы элементу, который внутри обертки можно было присвоить максимальную ширину( т.к. она нужна по дизайну ), потом поменял некоторые настройки и все заработало. Результат [тут](http://silencer.website/mdis/index.html%20%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82)

Всем спасибо, кто хотел помочь =)